# Primary Display option in BIOS

Tags: bios

I have changed my primary display option in BIOS (I don't remember what the choices were, they were 2, so I guess I switched from one to the other one). Now I'm not able to see the boot menu (like I used to do pressing F2).

And the OS boots directly. Does someone have any idea how I can enter my Boot Screen again?

Comment: Since my answer was off-target, I deleted it. OP has changed which *graphics card* is primary, not which monitor is primary.

Comment: Hi jpaugh, I believe now NVIDIA is my primary graphic card